# Minecraft: What is the name for the texture of the bar on the front of the screen during gameplay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to edit some textures in minecraft to match my skin, I've changed my inventory look but I cant figure out how to change the little bar that holds the HP level, hunger level, and the 9 items you can have on hand.

What is the name of the texture file?

Answer (score 2):

The name for the file containing the texture of the hotbar should be 'widgets', located in /assets/minecraft/textures/gui/widgets.png ...

In related news, the cursor should be in a file called 'icons'.

Source: [How do you change the cursor and the hotbar in/for a resource pack?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2xioxw/how_do_you_change_the_cursor_and_the_hotbar_infor/)